# Test result shows content from a database that it's not (supposed to be) connected to in test environment

Tags: node.js, testing, model-view-controller, environment-variables, chai

I'm writing tests for a CRUD Node app that uses EJS as a view engine. I expect res.text to show the content that was posted in the test database before the tests are run:

```
// test.js

const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const { app, mongooseConnection } = require("./app.js");

const blogSchema = require("./models/blog");
const Blog = mongooseConnection.model("Blog", blogSchema);

let testBlogsArray;

before(async () => {
  try {
    testBlogsArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      const testBlog = new Blog({
        title: `TEST title ${i + 1}`,
        snippet: `TEST snippet ${i + 1}`,
        body: `TEST body ${i + 1}`,
      });
      testBlogsArray.push(await testBlog.save());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

after(async () => {
  try {
    for (const key in mongooseConnection.collections) {
      await mongooseConnection.collections[key].deleteMany({});
    }
     await mongooseConnection.dropDatabase();
    await mongooseConnection.close();
    testBlogsArray = null;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

    describe("GET /", () => {
      it("should get all blogs from the test database", (done) => {
        chai
          .request(app)
          .get("/blogs") 
          .end((err, res) => {
            console.log(app.locals.settings.env) // says 'test'
            console.log(res.text) // renders development env view i.e. shows content from a db other than test db
            res.text.should.match(/all blogs/i); 
            res.text.should.match(/test title 1/i); // fails
            done();
          });
      });
    });
```

I have set up a separate database for test environment which I stated in my app.js file:

```
const dbURI = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? process.env.TEST_MONGO_URI : process.env.MONGO_URI;  
const mongooseConnection = mongoose.createConnection(dbURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

And I make sure NODE_ENV is set to 'test' every time tests are run:

```
// package.json
{...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha",
  }
...}
```

But somehow, res.text is showing the content from the database that I'm not supposed to be connected to when running tests.

1. I checked whether logging `app.locals.settings.env` within the `end()` block in the test shows a value other than 'test'. It doesn't.
2. I logged the dbURI string when running tests, it shows the test database URI.
3. I confirmed that the test data is indeed being stored in the test database by running the tests without the cleanup code in `after()`.

Answer (score 0):

*By the time I figured out what the problem was, I realized I didn't post enough of my code for anyone else to figure it out anyway, so I might as well save someone else's time...*

So when the problem was occurring, my `blogController.js` had this piece of code at the top:

```
const connection = require("../config/database");
const Blog = connection.models.Blog;
```

And the required file had this in it:

```
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  //...
})
```

This code ran every time right before a `.get("/")` request was sent in the test which resulted in `MONGO_URI` data unexpectedly showing in the `res.text` log.

I solved the problem by creating a single "source of truth" for the connection that considers different environments:

```
//root/config/database.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();

const dbURI = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test"
  ? process.env.TEST_MONGO_URI
  : process.env.MONGO_URI; 
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(dbURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

module.exports = connection;
```

...and refactoring the rest of my code to only use connection from this source.